# Comprehensions in Python to sample tuples from a list

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I am trying to get the list of three-element tuples from the list `[-4, -2, 1, 2, 5, 0]` using comprehensions, and checking whether they fulfil the condition `sum([] == 0)`. The following code works. However, there is no question that there ought to be an easier, much more elegant way of expressing these comprehensions:

```
[
    (i, j, k) for i in [-4, -2, 1, 2, 5, 0]
              for j in [-4, -2, 1, 2, 5, 0]
              for k in [-4, -2, 1, 2, 5, 0] if sum([i, j, k]) == 0
]
```

Output:

```
[(-4, 2, 2), (-2, 1, 1), (-2, 2, 0), (-2, 0, 2), (1, -2, 1), 
 (1, 1, -2), (2, -4, 2), (2, -2, 0), (2, 2, -4), (2, 0, -2), 
 (0, -2, 2), (0, 2, -2), (0, 0, 0)]
```

The question is searching for an expression like `(i, j, k) for i, j, k in [-4, -2, 1, 2, 5, 0]`.

Comment: Is repeted values allowed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to hide the nested loops in your list comprehension. Use the `repeat` parameter to set the number of loops over the list (i.e. the number of elements in the tuple):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> lst = [-4, -2, 1, 2, 5, 0]
>>> [x for x in itertools.product(lst, repeat=3) if sum(x) == 0]
[(-4, 2, 2),
 (-2, 1, 1),
 (-2, 2, 0),
 (-2, 0, 2),
 (1, -2, 1),
 (1, 1, -2),
 (2, -4, 2),
 (2, -2, 0),
 (2, 2, -4),
 (2, 0, -2),
 (0, -2, 2),
 (0, 2, -2),
 (0, 0, 0)]
```